# Simple OOP currency converter - follow-up

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns, unit-testing, unit-conversion

This is a follow up question on **[this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223322/simple-oop-currency-converter)**

This is what I changed on my previous code:

1. I use `Exchanger` and `PairCurrency` class instead of `Bank`
2. I renamed `addRate` and `addCommission` to `setRate` and `setCommission` respectively
3. `Exchanger` object contains multiple `PairCurrency` objects which can be added to `Exchanger` by `addPairCurrency()` method.

This is my code and tests:

```
import pytest

class DuplicatePairError(Exception):
    pass

class Exchanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pair_currencies = []
        self.commission = 0.015

    def addPairCurrency(self, pair_object):
        if pair_object in self.pair_currencies:
            raise DuplicatePairError('Cannot add duplicate pair of currency')

        self.pair_currencies.append(pair_object)

    @property
    def last_pair(self):
        return self.pair_currencies[-1]


    def getRate(self, pair):
        for pair_obj in self.pair_currencies:
            if pair_obj.name == pair:
                return pair_obj.rate

    def convert(self, src_dest, amount):
        return amount / self.getRate(src_dest) * (1-self.commission)


    def editRate(self,new_object):
        for pair_obj in self.pair_currencies:
            if pair_obj.name == new_object.name:
                 pair_obj.rate = new_object.rate

class PairCurrency:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setRate(self, rate):
        self.rate = rate

    def editRate(self, new_rate):
        self.rate = new_rate

    def __eq__(self, object):
        return self.name == object




def test_canInitializePair_CurrenciesListInExhangeClass():
    exchanger = Exchanger()

    assert exchanger.pair_currencies == []

def test_canSetRateinPairCurrencyClass():
    USD_GBP = PairCurrency('USDGBP')
    USD_GBP.setRate(2)

    assert USD_GBP.name == 'USDGBP'
    assert USD_GBP.rate == 2

def test_canSetCommisionInExchanger():
    exchanger = Exchanger()

    assert exchanger.commission == 0.015

@pytest.fixture()
def USD_GBP():
    USD_GBP = PairCurrency('USDGBP')
    USD_GBP.setRate(2)
    return USD_GBP

@pytest.fixture()
def GBP_USD():
    GBP_USD = PairCurrency('GBPUSD')
    GBP_USD.setRate(0.5)
    return GBP_USD

@pytest.fixture()
def exchanger(USD_GBP,GBP_USD):


    exchanger = Exchanger()
    exchanger.addPairCurrency(USD_GBP)
    exchanger.addPairCurrency(GBP_USD)
    return exchanger

def test_canAddPairCurrencyinExchangerClass(exchanger, USD_GBP, GBP_USD):


    assert USD_GBP == exchanger.pair_currencies[-2]
    assert GBP_USD == exchanger.last_pair

def test_cannotAddDuplicatePair(exchanger, USD_GBP):
    USD_GBP2 = PairCurrency('USDGBP')
    USD_GBP2.setRate(5)



    exchanger = Exchanger()
    exchanger.addPairCurrency(USD_GBP)
    with pytest.raises(DuplicatePairError) as excinfo:
        exchanger.addPairCurrency(USD_GBP2)
    assert str(excinfo.value) == 'Cannot add duplicate pair of currency'


def test_canEditRateInPairCurrencyClass(USD_GBP):


    USD_GBP.editRate(3)
    assert USD_GBP.rate == 3

    USD_GBP.editRate(4)
    assert USD_GBP.rate == 4

def test_canEditRateinExhangerClass(exchanger):
    USD_GBP = PairCurrency('USDGBP')
    USD_GBP.setRate(5)
    exchanger.editRate(USD_GBP)
    assert exchanger.getRate('USDGBP') == 5

def test_canConvertInExchangerClass(exchanger, USD_GBP, GBP_USD):

    assert exchanger.convert(src_dest = 'USDGBP', amount = 100) == 49.25
    assert exchanger.convert(src_dest='GBPUSD', amount=100) == 197
```

I have few questions:

1. How good is my OOP design?
2. Is my test list fine?
3. Should I remove `editRate()` in `PairCurrency` and just keep `editRate()` in `Exchanger`?
4. Do my classes violate the **SOLID Principle** ?
5. What I have to fix to improve my code and OOP design ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Set?

You have logic preventing duplicate currency pairs. The easier (and more performant) thing to do is to simply represent `pair_currencies` as a set instead of a list. When you add, it will automatically discard duplicates.

### snake_case

The standard is to name methods like your `last_pair` - i.e., `get_rate`.

### Lookups

You have a loop in `getRate` and `editRate` to try and find the correct currency. Instead, you should be using a dictionary, which does not require a loop.

### Remove duplicate methods

`editRate` and `setRate` do the exact same thing, so delete the former.

### Equality test is wrong

Your `__eq__` method should be comparing to an object instance, not a string. As such, you should be comparing `self.name` with `object.name`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would suggest you changing `PairCurrency` constructor from

```
class PairCurrency:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

to

```
class PairCurrency:
    def __init__(self, name, ratio):
         self.name = name
         self.ratio
```

There is literally no reason to make it different. This is not a functional class but rather DataStructure.

It's also much easier to create instances with

```
us = PairCurrency('US', 3)
```

than

```
us = PairCurrency('US')
us.setRate(3)
```

As stated above, `__eq__` method is wrong. It should be:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.name == other.name and self.rate == other.rate
```

Also there is no need to create your own structures like that.

Your `PairCurrency` class isn't better than just a simple python tuple.

```
PairCurrency('US', 3) == PairCurrency('US', 3) => true
('US', 3) == ('US', 3) => true
```

The only reason you would want to do that is to increase verbosity, but this can be achieved by using builtin `namedtuples`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

PairCurrency = namedtuple('PairCurrency', 'name rate')
us = PairCurrency('US', 3)
print(us) 
=> PairCurrency(name='US', rate=3)
```

Sets would work the same with `tuples`, `namedtuples` and your custom `PairCurrency` with custom `__eq__`.